# Redundant for loop output

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop

I'm trying to separate a long typedef(C) into its words, then print the second word of each line

```
variable = """int32_t  adc_cal_A;             / Simple point slope   calculation adjustment needed for the ADC */ \r\n
          int32_t  adc_cal_B;                 /* y = Ax + B */"""
list = variable.splitlines()

for line in list:
    wordlist =  line.split()

    for line in wordlist:
       output = wordlist[1][:-1]
       print output
```

It is successfully printing the second word of each line in my test list, but it repeats that word multiple times. This is the result:

```
adc_cal_A
adc_cal_A
adc_cal_A
adc_cal_A
adc_cal_A
adc_cal_A
adc_cal_A
adc_cal_A
adc_cal_A
adc_cal_A
adc_cal_A
adc_cal_A
adc_cal_A
adc_cal_B
adc_cal_B
adc_cal_B
adc_cal_B
adc_cal_B
adc_cal_B
adc_cal_B
adc_cal_B
adc_cal_B

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Anyone know why this is happening. Is there an easy solution?

Comment: don't use `list`, it's a keyword

Comment: You are iterating over `wordlist` but printing the variable name each time. You end up printing the variable name for _each word_ in each line.

Comment: Sounds silly but to understand the above comment just insert a `break` at the end of your code.

Comment: what @IgorRaush is suggesting is get rid of the line `for line in wordlist:`. Funny thing is it's in the title of the question - "redundant for loop"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple way to achieve what you're looking for:

```
variable = """int32_t  adc_cal_A;                 / Simple point slope   calculation adjustment needed for the ADC */ \r\n
          int32_t  adc_cal_B;                 /* y = Ax + B */"""

for num_line, line in enumerate(variable.splitlines()):
    try:
        print(f"line={num_line} token={line.split()[1]}")
    except Exception as e:
        # Probably line is empty?
        pass
```

Output:

```
line=0 token=adc_cal_A;
line=2 token=adc_cal_B;
```

If you just want the 2nd tokens without the other goodies, use `print(line.split()[1])`, ie:

```
adc_cal_A;
adc_cal_B;
```